# Is it possible to implement voice chat in a browser without plugins?

Tags: javascript, chat

[CampFireNow](http://campfirenow.com/tour) has a voice chat over the browser. It seems that you do not need any plugins to install to get it working. This is a contrast to Gmail, where I needed to install an app.

I would like to implement a similar feature for my application.  Is there a way to do this without requiring a plugin?

Comment: view the source with Firebug and see what it has under the hood.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992507/voice-chat-in-the-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash or Java would be the only things that would be browser agnostic. Else, you definitely need a plugin, unless the specific browser provides you a method to record.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used CampFireNow, but it probably uses Flash

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, so I can't look at the source.  I don't believe that there is a way to do this without any plugins at all, though.  My guess is that they are either using Flash or Java (probably Flash).

Comment: Correction: Flash is also a plug-in, although it is installed in many browsers to the point of omnipresence.

Comment: @Piskvor: Huh?  I never said that it wasn't a plugin, so how is that a correction?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes looking for a possible solution, WebRTC lets you do just that. For more info, visit https://webrtc.org/

From the website, *"WebRTC is a free, open project that provides browsers and mobile applications with Real-Time Communications (RTC) capabilities via simple APIs. The WebRTC components have been optimized to best serve this purpose."*

Comment: Just use WebRTC leak prevent -extension if you use this approach.