# Voice chat in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, node.js, voice

We are looking to implement a group -**voice**- chat in the browser using node.js on the server. Is this possible?

Comment: look here maybe it helpful for you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621642/node-js-creating-persistent-private-chat-rooms

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement voice chat in a browser without plugins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821311/is-it-possible-to-implement-voice-chat-in-a-browser-without-plugins)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want your solution to be purely JavaScript based on both, server and client side, then you would probably have to wait for the [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/blog/introducingwebrtc-anopenreal-timecommunicationsproject), [Device API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/NOTE-dap-api-reqs-20091015/) or [media capture](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-media-capture-20110414/) [API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-media-capture-api-20100928/) and then implement node.js backend for it.

Other than that it is, I would say, a question of Flash oriented APIs on the client side (for accessing devices such as cameras or microphones) and some kind of interoperability with node.js backend in case you don't want to take advantage of [Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server) or [Red5](http://www.red5.org/).

Comment: Yea we were hoping for something like WebRTC -  do you know if WebRTC is in any nightly builds for any browser yet?

Comment: I think in some dev version of chromium maybe. Code should be [here](http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/) and some samples in [this](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started) guide.

Answer (score 5):

I'm researching and working on the same problem.

This is my proposed stack:-

capturing voice on the client
https://github.com/jiehanzheng/Recorderjs/blob/master/README.md

encoding the captured speech so that it can be shared via Node
https://github.com/jpemartins/speex.js

sharing voice data with multiple users
node.js and socket.io

Somebody wrote a **THESIS** on this.  good read but some missing code in the samples
http://pure.ltu.se/portal/files/36285511/LTU-EX-2012-36247736.pdf

relevant question on so.  in particular look at answer by sirjamm
[How to Call SPEEX Audio Decode/Encode in HTML5 / JavaScript (Without Flash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134936/how-to-call-speex-audio-decode-encode-in-html5-javascript-without-flash)

If I get it working, will post the github ref here.

hth